# Yii2 column alias in searchModel

Tags: php, mysql, alias

I've got a problem with aliases, trying to get ActiveDataProvider with alias that is min value from 2 tables.

```
$query->select('karta_przyrzadu.*'); 
        $query->joinWith('dzialania');
        $query->addSelect(['dataVar1' => '(NOW() + interval karta_przyrzadu.co_zostalo day)']);
        $query->addSelect(['dzialania.data_plan as `dataVar2`']);
        $query->addSelect(['least(dataVar1, dataVar2) as nextActionDate']);
```

Vars in model are declared, and marked as safe in rules():

```
public $nextActionDate;
public $dateRangeStart;
public $dateRangeEnd;
public $dataVar1;
public $dataVar2;
```

### Filtering

```
if (!is_null($this->nextActionDate) && strpos($this->nextActionDate, ' - ') !== false ) {
            list($dateRangeStart, $dateRangeEnd) = explode(' - ', $this->nextActionDate);
            $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'dataVar2', $dateRangeStart, $dateRangeEnd]);
        }
```

## doesn't because of:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dataVar1' in 'field list'
```

The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `karta_przyrzadu`.*, (NOW() + interval co_zostalo day) AS `dataVar1`, `dzialania`.data_plan as `dataVar2`, least(dataVar1, dataVar2) as nextActionDate FROM `karta_przyrzadu` LEFT JOIN `dzialania` ON `karta_przyrzadu`.`id_przyrz` = `dzialania`.`id_przyrz_d` WHERE (`nextActionDate` BETWEEN '2017-02-18' AND '2017-02-24') AND (NOT (`status`='Wycofany')) GROUP BY `id_przyrz`) `c`

Anyone can help me?

Comment: whether the problem is from your select or alias, you can leave out the part  `(NOW() + interval co_zostalo day) AS dataVar1` and see whether you still get alias error for as `datavar2` is also your alias

Comment: I've checked that - even if i change code to:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `karta_przyrzadu`.*, NOW() + interval co_zostalo day AS `dataVar1`, `dzialania`.data_plan as `dataVar2`, least((select dataVar1), (select dataVar2)) as nextActionDate FROM `karta_przyrzadu` LEFT JOIN `dzialania` ON `karta_przyrzadu`.`id_przyrz` = `dzialania`.`id_przyrz_d` WHERE (`nextActionDate` BETWEEN '2017-02-23' AND '2017-02-23') AND (NOT (`status`='Wycofany')) GROUP BY `id_przyrz`) `c`
so there's no problem with datavars - but nextActionDate <- even if it's defined

Comment: Any solution to this please?